# Getting an error 500 but returned ok()

Tags: java, ajax, playframework-2.0, internal-server-error

I am working on an MVC project, using Java and Play framework, and I encountered a problem. Here is the interesting part of the code (I cleaned it a bit):

The controller:

```
public Result acceptInputSimulationPension() {
    if (request().getHeader(CONTENT_TYPE) == null) {
        return badRequest("error: no content type");
    }
    if (!request().getHeader(CONTENT_TYPE).contains("multipart/form-data")) {
        return badRequest("Error: wrong content type. Expected multipart/form-data, got " + CONTENT_TYPE);
    }

    Form<String> form = Form.form(String.class).bindFromRequest();
    Pension project = new Pension();

    project.setMaxloss(form.field("maxloss").value());
    // setting some other parameters...
    project.setIdUser(Application.user.getId());

    if (project.getMaxloss() == 0) {
        return badRequest("error: maxloss datalist malformed");
    }

    double[] flows = Application.getPensionFlows(project, (int) project.computeContributionYears(), (int) project.computeAdditionalIncomeNeeded());
    Savings savings = new Savings((int) project.getInitialContribution(), flows, (int) project.computeContributionYears() * 12);
    Ebean.save(project);

    session("init/pension/maxloss"+project.getId(), form.field("maxloss").value());
    // setting some other session variables...

    ObjectNode result = Application.jsonEncoder.encodeFinalSimulPension(project, savings.getSavings(), flows, false, true);
    result.put("id", project.getId());
    System.out.println("hello?");
    return ok("test");
}
```

I am returning ok("test") to make sure that the problem doesn't come from the result variable.

And the AJAX:

```
function  ajaxPOST_simulation(data, id, formName) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/input/simulation/"+formName,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (resp) {
        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function (resp) {
        alert("error: " + resp.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

The System.out.println("hello") is successfully displayed on my terminal, so I guess i am returning ok("test"), but i get this error as an alert:

```
error:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Execution exception</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU... etc.
```

How is this possible?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I just figured out that the HTML code corresponded a [NullPointerException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7cvN.png), but I still have no idea what could be NULL here. Even the result variable is not NULL and looks ok...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem didn't come from the json, neither from the ajax: I was just trying to do this:

```
session("init/pension/maxloss"+project.getId(), form.field("maxloss").value());
```

with a field that didn't exist anymore.
I thought that this kind of mistake would throw an exception and stop the program before it gets to the end of the function.